# Many-to-many Files Vlookup or Index-Match basic on specified cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying a vlookup to a closed workbook; however, it will not always be the same workbook. I was hoping I could reference the file name to a particular cell value and locate it from there. Here is the code I have.

```
Sub Vlookup()
Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Formula As String

Path = "C:\Users\Jwbeauch\Desktop\Schools\Chart of Accounts\["
FileName = Range("B1").Value & ".xlsx]COA'!"
Formula = "Vlookup(D3," & Path & FileName & Range("$B$15:$C$1000") & ", 2, 0)"
ActiveCell.Formula = Formula

     
     
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having though?  What happens when your code runs?

Comment: Hi Tim, the issue I am having is with the formula. The error message I receive is "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Vlookup()

Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Formula As String
Dim SheetName As String

Path = "C:\Users\Jwbeauch\Desktop\Schools\Chart of Accounts\"
FileName = "[" & Range("B1").Value & ".xlsx]"
SheetName = "COA" ' Need to enter sheet name you are looking up

Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D3,'" & Path & FileName & SheetName & "'!" & ("$B$15:$C$1000") & ",2,0)"
ActiveCell.Formula = Formula

End Sub
```